# Pesquisa php em site externo!

Tags: php

Estou começando um projeto de um site cujo preciso realizar pesquisas de palavras chaves e obter os resultados, o site será parecido com o **youtube**, gostaria de saber se é possível a partir de uma `textbox`no meu formulário eu enviar informações para o sistema de busca do **youtube**, e recuperar o resultado e mostrar nesse site os vídeos(links) resultados da buscar não sei muito de `php`, mais já vi que a google disponibiliza um sistema pronto de pesquisa interna para site, onde cadastro-o e o script deles procuram resultados internos 
Se for possível fazer isso(busca em site externo) se puderem me dar o "empurrão" eu resolvo o resto.

Comment: porque pergunta pendente? aceitei a resposta do Rebelox, já dei inicio ao projeto, fiz uns teste com a api `php-youtube-api` e parece servir para o que preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias APIs que permitem obter o conteudo de websites, como por exemplo o **[simpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**.

Porém a tua questão baseia-se em num site que contém uma própria API (**[Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)**) com esta API poderás obter os dados que quiseres, inclusive **[o resultado de pesquisas](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/search.php)**.

Poderás também utilizar o **[php-youtube-api](https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api)** (pode ser encontrado no GitHub) que, segundo o autor, foi desenhado com o intuito de facilitar os programadores na busca de dados no YouTube.

Devo dizer que estas duas APIs (**[Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)** e o **[PHP-Youtube-API](https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api)**) necessitam de uma **key**, obtida através do *Google Developers Console*, isto está tudo documentado no **guia do Youtube Data API**.

Comment: muito obrigado @RebeloX! tudo que eu precisava saber, abraço.